# GTA IV: EFLC crashes after loading screen

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-iv, games-for-windows-live

I've just installed GTA IV: EFLC and it was crashing just after the Rockstar blue logo. So I installed Games for Windows – Live then it worked and it showed the 2 episodes: The Lost and Damned, and The Ballad of Gay Tony.

Whenever I choose any of them and click play, it loads showing me some pictures of the characters then it says "GTA: Episodes from liberty city has stopped working" Any help please?

Comment: We need more information. Are your Nvidia/AMD drivers current?   Does your hardware meet the requirements of the game.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was trying to fix searched the web but couldn't find any help.One day I downloaded multiiv and give it a try to play EFLC online. After when I have finished downloading I run the game through multiiv and it asked me for game location I gave it and successfully run after that there was no such thing like multiiv control panel. The only thing I just could see was the same as usual , I was shocked , then I thought what to do now.I went to the web(http://www.moddb.com/mods/multiv) and clicked on that (You can join the server Here or directly on 37.122.211.8:5000)/it updated my game I think and after that when I just run the TBOG and a miracle happened. It successfully worked. I don't think that if could be helpful for you but you can try your luck thanks!

Sorry for my bad english